# Apply function to a specific number of rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, lambda, pandas

I have a weather data and I would need to apply a function to a specific number of rows. For example, to calculate mean values of every 10 or 15 rows. The number of rows is important because there are quite many missing values in dates and I don't want to rely on it.

I tried `groupby` but there I can only specify hours or minutes. Anyway I would like to apply any function independent from `DateTime index`.

I think slicing `DF` would be an option `df[:9]` but I don't know how to apply this to all rows?

Simple example below:

```
index=date_range('2013-1-1 00:00:03', '2013-01-31  23:59:03', freq='1min')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index),3),index=index)

df.groupby(df.index.map(lambda t: t.minute))
```

Hoping for any advice.

Comment: Say you want to combine every 10 rows but your frame has 53 rows.  What do you want done with the extra?  Should they be in a group or not?

Comment: Also what is the function you want to apply? Does `df.resample('10min', how=<your_func>)` work?

Comment: @DSM extra rows can be ignored.

Comment: @TomAugspurger I would like to use your advice but problem is that I can't use minutes as a frequency. I must use rows :/ The code is only to present an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **@TomAugspurger**, I've found a solution.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19897550/2669472):

```
 df.resample(df.index.freq * 10, how='mean')
```